# How to partially declare a struct that is typedef'ed when in an include file

Tags: c, include, typedef

I'm trying to minimize interdependence of #include files as a general practice.

In xxx.h I have:

```
struct my_struct;  // partial decl to satisfy use of my_struct*
void funct(struct my_struct* ms);  // uses the partial def
```

How to do a similar partial decl with a typedef'd struct?
I have an actual decl in some third #include that looks like (say in yyy.h):

```
typedef struct my_data_s {
  int ival;
  ... struct's other components ...
} my_data_t;
```

I just want a representative decl in xxx.h that reference the typedef:

```
typedef struct my_data_s  my_data_t;  // actual full decl is elsewhere
void funct2(my_data_t* md);
```

This attempt causes 'redefinition of typedef my_data_t' error. (Using gcc 4.4.3 / Ubuntu 10.4) Other random search attempts (e.g., add '{}' to typedef) also give errors.

I know the compiler only needs to know that the function requires a pointer, so it seems like this should be possible. So far, found nothing that compiles w/o errors/warnings.

I've looked at the other questions and answers, could not find this problem addressed. Seems like there should be a well-known way to do this(?!) (I know that I can #include yyy.y whenever I #include xxx.h - trying to avoid such dependencies.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what our group decided to do. It represents a compromise of several conflicting requirements/desires. I am posting to show another approach, so readers of the post have some variety to choose from. It represents the best answer for our situation.

### obj_a_defs.h

```
// contains the definition
// #include'd only by other .h files
...
#define ... // as needed for struct definition
...
typedef struct obj_a {
  ...
} obj_a;
```

### obj_a.h

```
// contains the 'full info' about obj_a: data and behaviors
// #include'd by other .c files
...
#include "obj_a_defs.h"
...
// declares functions that implement 
// the behaviors associated with obj_a
```

### obj_a.c

```
...
#include "obj_a.h"
...
// implementations of functions declared in obj_a.h
```

### obj_b.h

```
// a 'user' of obj_a that uses obj_a as arg
#include "obj_a_defs.h"  // to get the typedef    
...
int some_b_funct(obj_a* obja, ...);
...
```

### obj_b.c

```
// Defines the 'contract' that this implementation
// is meeting.
#include "obj_b.h"
...
// This .c file includes obj_a.h only if it
// uses the functions defined for obj_a.
// If obj_a is used only to 'pass through'
// to other modules, there's no need for 
// this include.
#include "obj_a.h"  // only if obj_b uses 
...
// obj_b's function implementations
```

Rationale / Conditions

- typedef and struct kept together
- a .c file that uses obj_X must #include "obj_X.h"
  to show that use
- avoid .h files including other .h files in general;
  only 'defs.h' files are #include'd in .h files.
- avoid #include'ing a file just to handle dependencies;
  IOW avoid #include'ing obj_a.h just because it's used in obj_b.h

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the simple approach:?

xxx.h

```
struct my_data_s;
typedef struct my_data_s my_data_t;
```

yyy.h

```
#include "decl.h"
struct my_data_s {
   int foo;
};
```

Comment: Has the same error as my one-line version. Thanks for the idea tho!

Comment: @ArtSwri: You didn't really do what he said, did you?  The important part is not to repeat the `typedef` (which is exactly what the error message complains about).

Answer (score 3):

C99 doesn't allow to repeat a `typedef`, C11 does.

Just do the `typedef` only once and always have it first:

```
typedef struct my_data  my_data;
```

There also is no need to chose different names for the `struct` tag and the `typedef` identifier.

Comment: (I know you can use the same name for struct and typedef, should have mentioned that. We're following a coding spec as ordered.) Doing the typedef once means separating it from the struct decl (or do I misunderstand?)

Comment: @ArtSwri: Why does it matter if the `typedef` is separated from the actual `struct` declaration?  It'd still be next to the forward declaration.

Comment: @jamesdlin, the `struct` tag itself doesn't need any forward declaration. Because of the `struct` keyword, it is clear that one is referring to a structure. First placing the `typedef` separately allows you to always use the `typedef` name without the `struct` keyword, even inside the actual declaration of the `struct`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, I know this.  My comment was directed at Art, who had a silly objection to using the `typedef` only at the site of the forward declaration.  Who cares if it's separated from the concrete definition.